# Redirecting complex URL Aliases in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, path

I need to redirect sample.com/newdomain/calendar to an external link however I already have a rewrite rule in place to redirect sample.com/newdomain/ to newdomain.sample.com/ so when I enter sample.com/newdomain/calendar into the web browser it takes me to newdomain.sample.com/calendar. How can I override the original rewrite I have written to allow sample.com/newdomain/calendar to redirect to an external url.

The rewrite rule that will redirect any url containing /newdomain is:

```
# Redirect /newdomain to newdomain.sample.com
RewriteRule ^newdomain(/.*)?$ http://newdomain.sample.com$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What's your exact question?

Answer (score 0):

You can place new redirect rule above the previous rule and make sure to clear your browser cache before testing:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^newdomain/calendar/?$ http://external.site.com/ [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^newdomain(/.*)?$ http://newdomain.sample.com$1 [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```